# Talents/Skills we possess as Humans

Tags: reincarnation

I have a strong desire to be an actor but I don't possess such skills... So is it possible that after reincarnation I come back in a body/form with acting skills. (I know this is a childish question but please help me)
I really want to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can be reborn in this life as an actor. In a fundamental way, life is like a stage and we are the actors in the play. I guarantee you that your desires will lead to results.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a childish question at all.  Buddha guaranteed you will get or become whatever you want if you have, faith (saddha), precepts (sila), knowledge in Buddha's teachings (sutta), giving (jacca) and wisdom (panna which is either meditation or seeing raise and fall of all things.  It is in sankharuppatti sutta.
Other things Buddha said would help which I don't remember the name of sutta, you will be successful in whatever your intention if you have ; precepits, living not far from jahnna, have vipassana,  stay in sunyata. 
Good luck with your goal.  And if you are a Buddhist, don't forget to work towards becoming a stream enterer too.  Its a guarantee destination even after you get what you want or want to be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you can accept [to born in hell after an actor's life](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.002.than.html). Because an actor is a mijjhā-ajīva in 8-mijjhā-magga, akusala-kammapatha-offense career that buddha said **["reborn in hell"](http://tipitaka.de/roman/tipitaka%20(mula)/suttapitaka/samyuttanikaya/mahavaggapali/11.%20sotapattisamyuttam.html#para1022)**, 7th of 10 akusala kammapatha.

you just expect and attention at actor's life in every time  of your life, especially when you making a merit.

I love to sing and act like you, but I try to avoid to be in this career. Because they are direct hindrance careers for the meditations.

Comment: Related: The question "[Will actors really go to hell?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7663/471)"

Answer (score 0):

Light,

The skill, actually being very mindfull and hold on certain mind states, which are required for an actor, are the same means one would use in the practice of the path to liberation.

So best if one starts to become a real actor here and now. One able to set his mind by will1 on every kind of way of thinking. Good to train that, and good to memorize the text. Best try to be a Dhammic actor.

There are at times, as far as seen, many monks and nuns public visible, who have been actors before.

Start to act like a Noble One. Right here and now. Train it all day and night, everywhere.

Becoming an Arahat means to become a real actor, not limited in his freedom of appearing, taking on what ever skillful profile at wish and is therefore regarded as real Star.

What character would you like to act? Buy acting is one called great.

And the meaning of that goes rightdirect to the main question: **Talents/Skills we possess as Humans**

Not by birth is one a human with inherent skills, but by deeds, by acts, one can be rightly called human. So if not a sillful actor, not much chance to be rightly called on with human skills:

> O! Gotama, we have a dispute on birth.
>   Bhāradvāja says 'by birth a Brahmin is made'
>   And I say 'by actions a Brahmin is made. '
>
> [Vāseṭṭha Sutta: To the Brahmin Vasettha](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.098.uppa_en.html)

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*

Answer (score 0):

The advice given by [Ajaan Lee Dhammadharo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajahn_Lee) in his essay "[The Skill of Release](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/lee/skillof.html)" should be helpful to you:

> When we're true in what we do — when we don't stop or grow lax or give
>   up — the results, even if they show up slowly, are bound to be great.
>   The fact that they are all growing at once is what makes them slow.
>   It's like a tree with lots of branches to protect itself and give lots
>   of shade. It's bound to grow more slowly than a banana tree, which has
>   only one stem and gives good fruit, but is exposed to lots of dangers.
>   Some people get results quickly; others more slowly. The slower people
>   shouldn't compare themselves or compete with the quick ones. The quick
>   ones shouldn't compete with the slow ones. It's like polishing boards
>   and mirrors. Polishing a mirror so that you can see your reflection in
>   it doesn't take all that much talent, because the nature of the mirror
>   is already reflective. But to polish a board so that you can see your
>   reflection in it, even though it may take a long time, is a sign of
>   real expertise.

This basically means that you should have determination and perseverance towards achieving your goals, in this very lifetime. And don't compare yourself to those much better than you, for their path would be different from your's. Of course, some goals may not make sense, for e.g. if I wasn't born in the USA, then I cannot become the President of the USA.

In [MN57](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/23.11-Kukkuravatika-S-m57-piya.pdf), the Buddha said of the ascetic who had taken the vow to live like a dog, that if he lived his life behaving like a dog, thinking like a dog and having the mind of a dog, fully and without break, then he will be reborn in the company of dogs in future, if his vow is successful.

So, similarly, I would surmise that if you vow to become an actor, and take the effort to try to become an actor, study acting, practise acting, thinking like an actor etc., fully and without break, then you could be reborn in a destination where it is conducive for you to become an actor and also possess the talent of acting. Such is speculated of child prodigies too.